# Определить центр прямоугольника

Tags: математика

Не знаю, как точно называется. Допустим, есть прямоугольник такого вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как определить его центр? Система координат декартова, координаты каждой вершины известны(x, y). Или подскажите, в какую сторону курить.

Comment: Составляйте уравнения диагоналей и потом ищите точку их пересечения. Аналитическая геометрия это умеет. Вопрос вообще не про IT, IMHO...

Comment: Благодарю, помогло

Comment: Для average какая библиотека нужна ?

Comment: @Владилсав вычисление середины отрезка. Можете написать и сами, это просто псевдоимя функции

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Должно работать для любого параллелепипеда:

```
xc = average(x0, x1, x2, x3)
yc = average(y0, y1, y2, y3)
```

Достаточно даже 2 противоположных вершин:

```
xc = average(x0, x1)
yc = average(y0, y1)
```

Comment: Единственное - я бы в последней формуле исправил x1, y1 на x2, y2 :)